# Deciphering a libc element in a stack trace

Tags: python, linux, stack-trace, boost-python

I have one element in my stack trace I am not able to understand:

`/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x370b0)[0x7ff622fdb0b0]`

What I don't get is, what is the `(+0x370b0)`. I'd expect to see a function before the `+`.

Does this mean the trace couldn't get the function call, and is just referencing the offset in the shared library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably refers to a *static* function inside the *libc*, whose name is not a symbol visible e.g. to the dynamic loader, or to [backtrace(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/backtrace.3.html)

So the backtrace sees a function address but is not able to convert it to a symbol. See e.g. [dladdr(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dladdr.3.html) (which won't find the *lacking* name, but could find some public names close to it).

Perhaps having debug variant of the `libc` might help (at least with a suitably configured `gdb`), try installing some package like `libc6-dbg`